# Use Sympy with Pypy

Tags: python, sympy, pypy

I have installed Python 2.7 and 3.5 on a Mac running with El Capitan. Moreover, I use the package Sympy (installed with pip) with python. I wanted to run my code with Pypy (installed with homebrew) but it seems that Pypy doesn't find Sympy and says:

> "No module named sympy"

I am not an expert at all and don't know what to do now. Sympy works well with python 2 and 3 but not with Pypy.

I appreciate every answer, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyPy packages are separate from Python packages. You can install SymPy into PyPy with

```
pypy -m pip install sympy
```